# How to change marker size in Google Maps API v3 with Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have added a few markers on my map but when I run my app, I see the markers to be very small. I have created a custom icon with the `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi` dimensions but I still see them small.

This is how add the markers to the map:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Marker");
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_pin));
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

And this is how my map looks like:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

How to change marker size a little bit to be more visible?

Comment: what is your images size?

Comment: increase image size

Comment: @masoudvali mdpi -> 24x24, hdpi -> 32x32, xhdpi -> 48x48 and xxhdpi -> 64x64.

Comment: @ClickSolApps You say that I need to create bigger images? What are the recommended sizes?

Comment: as per your requirement how big you want to display..

Comment: @ClickSolApps Please see my edited post. Seeing this, what are the recommended sizes?

Comment: you take large size of images after convert android required mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi dimensions

Comment: @VenkiWAR I didn't understood you, can you please be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: take big size(High Quality) marker Images.than you convert that images in to android resource dimensions

Comment: online android icons converter available use that for convert Big size marker images to android icons

Comment: @VenkiWAR This is what I have done, I have taken the big image and converted to smaller sizes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, choose the larger image and make an image asset for all sizes. 
For that Right click on the drawable folder and select new -> Image Asset -> select appropriate options and select image. finish and it will automatically create all size of images. Use this image as the marker.

So, now at the end, you have the only solution is that use large size image into the marker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there any way to achieve this using my requirements?

Comment: Yes, the only way is that you can create the custom marker and set it.

Comment: There isn't another way, by set the dimensions programmatically or change the image size, as @ClickSol Apps recommended?

Comment: So, now at the end, you have the only solution is that use large size image into the marker.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Add the last comment into your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this if hope it will help you if not tell me to delete the answer ...!

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(String drawableName,int width, int height){
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, width, height, false);
}
```

then

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title("New Marker").position(yourGivenPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizeBitmap("your drawable name",72,64))));
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) and the extension [Script Fu Save Android icons](https://github.com/ruleant/script-fu-save-android-icons) to create all my **mipmap** or **icons** in my apps.

After install the script, you get this menu in the menu bar:

[image: Screenshot of GIMP]

After click on "Save Android Icons...", you'll get this window:

[image: Screenshot of the window to save icons]

The extension exports all icons according with Android Icon's Sizes:

[image: Screenshot of folders]

**After generate all icons, just move them to your project folder**

Comment: Thanks Carlos for this answer.